# How to make circles around Marker be created and removed when Marker is clicked on the react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, popup, react-leaflet, eventhandler

I think this problem is to use Popup or eventHandler. But when i used Popup, The circle is created but not removed.
And I have no idea how to make a circle using eventHandlers.
This First Code is use popup about this porblem.

```
            <MapContainer
                center={[48.864716, 2.349]}
                zoom={2}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                zoomControl={false}
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                minZoom={2}
                maxZoom={5}
                doubleClickZoom={false}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Polygon positions={overline} />
                <Marker position={[36.5, 130]} >
                    <Popup >Korea
                        <Circle center={[36.5, 130]} radius={1000000} />
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            </MapContainer>
```

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhW4d.png)

The Code with eventHandler.

```
<MapContainer
                center={[48.864716, 2.349]}
                zoom={2}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                zoomControl={false}
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                minZoom={2}
                maxZoom={5}
                doubleClickZoom={false}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Polygon positions={overline} />
                <Marker position={[36.5, 130]} eventHandlers ={{click : (e) => drawCircle(e.latlng)}}>
                    <Popup >Korea</Popup>
                </Marker>
            </MapContainer>
```

[How it looks with event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvyUN.png)

Please help me

I used both EventHandler and popup. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you include more code or some codesandbox example

Comment: yes update right now

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, Circle } from 'react-leaflet';
import "./test.css"

function Test_full_map() {

    const drawCircle = (position) => {
        console.log(position)
        return (<Circle center={position} radius={10000} />)
    }

    return (
        <div id='map'>
            <MapContainer
                center={[48.864716, 2.349]}
                zoom={2}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                zoomControl={false}
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                minZoom={2}
                maxZoom={5}
                doubleClickZoom={false}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={[36.5, 130]}
                //eventHandlers ={{click : (e) => drawCircle(e.latlng)}} //use eventHandler
                >
                    <Popup closeButton={true}>Korea
                        <Circle center={[36.5, 130]} radius={1000000} //use Popup
                        /> 
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test_full_map;
```

This Code is total Code. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I think you can edit the main question and include the full code there, and remove this answer

Answer (score 0):

This can work

```
     // set initial value for circle
     const [showCircle, setShowCircle] = useState(false);

     const onMarkerClick = (r) => {
       // e.preventDefault();
       console.log('marker click')
       // toggle circle
       setShowCircle(s => !s) 
     }


        <MapContainer
            center={[48.864716, 2.349]}
            zoom={2}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            zoomControl={false}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            minZoom={2}
            maxZoom={5}
            doubleClickZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Polygon positions={overline} />
            <Marker 
               position={[36.5, 130]} 
               // add event handler here
               eventHandlers={{ click: onMarkerClick }}
             >
                <Popup >Korea
                    // show circle conditionally when marker is clicked
                   { showCircle && <Circle center={[36.5, 130]} radius={1000000} />}
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
```

Few pointers
name of `drawCircle` needs to be changed to `DrawComponent` needs [to start with capital letter](https://drawCircle%20component%20needs%20to%20start%20with%20capital%20%20letter%20and%20needs%20to%20be%20outside%20the%20main%20compoent%20for%20performance%20reasons) and needs to be [outside the main component](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components) for performance reasons

Hope this helps yout to solve the problem

Comment: Thak you!!!  The last part of the traffic jam was solved!!

Comment: Welcome glad it helped you, consider making it as answered and upvoting, Cheers